# wkhtmltopdf sometimes not rendering javascript

Tags: php, javascript, linux, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to convert pages to pdf, through php. This works well on a windows and a ubuntu server, however, on a different linux server, it sometimes (~5 out of 6 times) doesn't execute the javascript (the pdf only contains data that wasn't generated/modified by javascript).

For instance, I'm using it to render some pages containing jqplot graphics.
The server having the issues seems to work well with external links, but when using a link pointing to itself, it fails to load the javascript most of the times.

I used the static binaries (v 0.9.9 and v0.11.0), and they both fail the same way. Using --javascript-delay (or --redirect-delay) doesn't have any effect (other than waiting for the pdf longer to generate).
On v0.11.0 I also used --window-status, which usually blocked the server for a short time (probably because javascript was never loaded, so window.status was not set).

Also, the output from wkhtml doesn't show any errors/warnings when javascript isn't loaded.

Any ideas or suggestions on what can cause this would help.

**Edit:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$.atk4(function(){ $('#myrealm_charts_jqplot').univ().jqplot(...pramas);
$('#myrealm_charts_jqplot_5').univ().jqplot(...params);
$('#myrealm_charts_jqplot_6').univ().jqplot(...params);
$('#myrealm_charts_jqplot_7').univ().jqplot(...params);
; });
});
</script>
```

...

```
<body class="atk-fullscreen gs-10-fluid atk-sticky">
    <div class="gs-wrap atk-layout">
        <div id="Content">
            <div id="myrealm_charts" class="page_charts">
                <div style="height: '' ;width:'600px';">
                    <div id="myrealm_charts_jqplot" class=" pdf-analytics-chart" style="">

                    </div>
                </div>
                ...
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The page doesn't have any errors reported by firebug.

Comment: Can we get some example HTML+JS that fails to test with?

Comment: Everything seems to fail on localhost. I'm using jQuery in most pages. When I am using wkhtmltopdf(same version) from other server on the same link it works fine. I have updated the question with some sample code.